# making a ordered pair from a two tables in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I had to recreate a youtube video that shows eight points moving in a straight lines but makes a circle rolling on the edges. I eventually made the program but I'm trying to generalize it so I can make it with different shapes. I used the code I had before but I am having trouble making an ordered pair that will work with the code. Every time I compile I get an error saying the points have to be ordered pairs but I can't figure out how to make the two tables ordered pairs.

```
p = 8; (*Number of points*)
\[Phi] = \[Pi]/p; (*Phase Shift*)
n = 1; \ (*Some integer*)
nump = 8; (* Number of points*)
total = nump - 1;  (* Shift number of points by -1*)

w[t_] := t^n; (* Random angular frequency*)
\[Theta][q_] = \[Phi]*q;
A1[q_] := Cos[\[Theta][q]];
A2[q_] := Sin[\[Theta][q]];
x[t_] = A1[q]*Cos[w[t] + \[Theta][q]];
y[t_] = A2[q]*Cos[w[t] + \[Theta][q]];
x1t = Table[ A1[q]*Cos[w[t] + \[Theta][q]], {q, 0, total}];
y1t = Table[ A2[q]*Cos[w[t] + \[Theta][q]], {q, 0, total}];



(*mylist = Transpose[List[x1t,y1t]]*)
mylist = Flatten[{x1t, y1t}, {2}]


pcircle = 
ParametricPlot[{Transpose[List[x1t, y1t]], {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}, {t, 0, 
2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
Animate[Show[pcircle, 
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Black, 
Point[Dynamic[{Flatten[{x1t, y1t}, {2}]}]]}]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi], 
AppearanceElements -> None}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a scoping problem, the animation iterator `t` is not the same as the global `t` in `x1t,y1t`.  This works:

```
Animate[Show[pcircle, 
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Black, 
    Point[Dynamic[{Flatten[{x1t,y1t}/. t -> ta, {2}]}]]}]], {ta, 0, 2 \[Pi], 
  AppearanceElements -> None}]
```

you could also fix this by making `x1t` explicitly a function of `t`

```
x1t[t_] = ...
```

then using `x1t[t]` everywhere.